# $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, function Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ Riemann integrable.

There exists step functions $g_k$ and $h_k$ defined on $[a,b]$ such as:

- $g_k \leq f \leq h_k$ sur $[a,b]$,
- $0 \leq \int_a^b h_k (x) dx - \int_a^b g_k(x) dx \leq \frac{1}{k}$,
- $\int_a^b f(x)dx = \lim\limits_{k \rightarrow +\infty} \int_a^b h_k(x) dx = \lim\limits_{k \rightarrow +\infty} \int_a^b g_k(x) dx$.

We have also $$g(x) = \sup\{g_k(x)\mid k \in \mathbb{N}^* \}\quad\text{and}\quad h(x) = \inf\{h_k(x)\mid k \in \mathbb{N}^* \}.$$ 
Naturally we have $g_k \leq g \leq f \leq h \leq h_k$.

I have to prove that 
$$\int_{[a,b]} |h-g| d \lambda < \infty\ \ \text{ and }\int_{[a,b]} (h-g) d \lambda = 0.$$

As $g,h \in L^1$ and $g \leq h$, I note :

\begin{split}
\int_{[a,b]} |h-g| d \lambda  &= \int_{[a,b]} |\inf\{h_k\}-\sup\{g_k\} | d \lambda  \\ 
&= \int_{[a,b]} \inf\{h_k\}-\sup\{g_k\}  d \lambda  \\ 
&= \int_{[a,b]} \inf\{h_k\} d\lambda - \int_{[a,b]} \sup\{g_k\} d\lambda \\
&= \int_{[a,b]} h d\lambda - \int_{[a,b]} g d \lambda  
\end{split}

$ \int_{[a,b]} g d \lambda \leq  \int_{[a,b]} h d\lambda$ because $g \leq h$ and $g,h \in L^1$.
Then, $\int_{[a,b]} |h-g| d \lambda < \infty$.

That's what I have done, but I don't know how to prove 
$$\int_{[a,b]} (h-g)d\lambda = 0.$$ 
Could someone help me ? I'm a beginner in Riemann/Lebesgue integration.

Comment: Hint: $0 \leqslant \int_a^b |h-g|  \leqslant \int_a^b h_k -\int_a^b g_k < 1/k$